# Setting onTouch for a moving object

Tags: android, image, listener

I have been attempting to set an onTouch listener to this image all day and have made no real progress.  No matter how I try to put it together it just won't seem to work.  I have attempt to put it in the onCreate before the handler is set and after the handler is set to no avail.  Is there something here that I do not understand?  Any insight or advice on how to accomplish this would be ever-so appreciated.  Thanks in advance!  This is a wonderful community.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView mImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            mImage = (ImageView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.Myimage);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new    
 LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*500 + 1);
            params.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*500 + 1);

            mImage.setLayoutParams(params);

            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
    r.run();
    }
}
```

Everything here, without the inclusion of an onTouch listener, works perfectly well.

Comment: Have you registered the onTouch listener to the `ImageView` by calling `setOnTouchListener()`?

Comment: I have tried that, but I get an error there, too...

Comment: I just tried your code and actually I didn't find any issues. Could you post more detail, including the layout XML, the `OnTouchListener` that you implement/override, how and where you registered the onTouch listener, and if there is error, post your logcat?

Comment: Upon adding the onTouchListener (with no errors in code) I get this output from logcat during activity crash:

java.io.filenotfound exception  access denied.

no such warning prior to adding the code.

In my xml I am using a custom class.  Could this be interfering with my code in some way?

Comment: I implemented these listeners in the oncreate method before the handler and runnable
I have tried adding just an "onclicklistener" with the same effect.

Comment: Does the app crash after you touch the image? It seems that the issue is regarding file I/O (file not found). Perhaps the permission? The location of the file?

Comment: Don't I feel stupid now... the problem was that I was implementing the listener before "mImage=(ImageView)..."
I noticed the problem and added after, no more crashing :D
Thank you for walking through this silly problem with me